# Alter Table, Add Column and Set column value in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to, in the same query, add a column to an existing table and set that column's value using case when?

```
ALTER TABLE #totalrevenue
ADD TotalRevenue_2003 Int CASE WHEN (Full2003 + Half2003 = 0) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END 
FROM data.revenuesummary
WHERE #totalrevenue.ID = data.revenuesummary.ID'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think so.   Why?

Comment: No you can't do this. ALTER is DDL and changing the data is DML. They are NOT the same thing. Split this into two statements. First alter the table and then immediately update it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Computed columns?
Read more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Tiny example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Products 
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
  , Full2003 smallint
  , Half2003 smallint
  , TotalRevenue2003 AS IIF(Full2003 + Half2003 = 0, NULL, 1)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.#Products
    (Full2003, Half2003)
VALUES
    (2, 3),
    (2, 2),
    (2, -2)

SELECT *
FROM dbo.#Products
```

Results in:

```
ID  Full2003    Half2003    TotalRevenue2003
1   2           3           1
2   2           2           1
3   2           -2          NULL
```

Comment: In the OP, it looks like the new column needs to reference values in a joined table.